# 'This page cannot be displayed' error on long running ColdFusion 9 page

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, server-error

We have a long running ColdFusion script running on ColdFusion 9 which is erroring with the following message:

```
This page cannot be displayed 

Internal system error while processing the request for this page (http:///www.example.com).

Please retry this request.

If this condition persists please contact your corporate network administrator and provide the code shown below.

Notification codes

(1, INTERNAL_ERROR, http:///www.example.com)
```

I haven't been able to determine what part of ColdFusion is generating these and don't have any other information as I haven't been able to reproduce the error and only have details from a screenshot.

Does anyone know what might be generating this error or how I can find out more information about it?

Comment: Have you checked the CF error logs?

Comment: They will probably indicate a java heap space error.

Comment: This message is generic and points to Network issue. The ColdFusion Application and Exception logs would have logged the errors. Check them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try/catch block to wrap your code and have it send you an email with all the error details (or you could log these to your database or write them to a log, etc).

```
<cftry>

    <!--- your code goes here --->

    <!--- catch and email any exceptions --->       
    <cfcatch type="any">

        <cfmail to="your-email" from="your-email" subject="something" type="html">

            <h3>An Error Occurred on #cfi.script_name#</h3>

            <h3><strong>DATE:</strong> #dateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy") & " " & timeFormat(now(), "hh:mm:ss")#</h3>

            <br />
            <br />
            <cfif isDefined("cfcatch")>
                <h5>catch object:</h5>
                <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
                <br />
                <br />
            </cfif>
            <cfif isDefined("ERROR")>
                <h5>Error object:</h5>
                <cfdump var="#ERROR#">
                <br />
                <br />
            </cfif>
            <cfif isDefined("cgi")>
                <h5>cgi object:</h5>
                <cfdump var="#cgi#">
                <br />
                <br />
            </cfif>
            <cfif isDefined("variables")>
                <h5>variables object:</h5>
                <cfdump var="#variables#">
                <br />
                <br />
            </cfif>
            <cfif isDefined("form")>
                <h5>form object:</h5>
                <cfdump var="#form#">
                <br />
                <br />
            </cfif>
            <cfif getapplicationMetadata().sessionmanagement and isDefined("session")>
                <h5>session object:</h5>
                <cfdump var="#session#">
                <br />
                <br />
            </cfif>
            <cfif isDefined("local")>
                <h5>local object:</h5>
                <cfdump var="#local#">
                <br />
                <br />
            </cfif>

        </cfmail>

    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```